# Ruby add a nested key to an existing hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm stuck on what appears to be a very simple problem.

If I have a transactions array `[#<payer: "Robert", dollar: 100, cent: 10>]`

```
totals = Hash.new(0)
transactions.each do |t|
  totals[t.payer] += t.dollar
end
totals
```

the code above will return `{"Robert"=>100}`. What I am looking for is something closer to `{"Robert" => { dollar: 100 }}`

So I attempted

```
totals = Hash.new(0)
transactions.each do |t|
  totals[t.payer][:dollar] += t.dollar
end
totals
```

but this returns a `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` Error. if I change the `[:dollar]` to `["dollar"]` it returns a `no implicit conversion of String into Integer`

What is the root of the my problem?

Comment: If your array had other transactions by Robert and others, your code might produce, say, `h = { 'Robert'=>180, 'Thelma'=>240 }`. You could then write `h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = { dollar: h[k] } }; h #=> { 'Robert'=>{ :dollar=>180 }, 'Thelma'=>{ :dollar=>240 } }`. I like this approach because it breaks the problem into two smaller problems: calculating totals and formatting. I think that is easiest to understand and facilitates testing and maintenance.

Comment: I lean in another direction altogether and favor real classes instead of an ad-hoc hash. The hashes are closer to that, e.g., here the people are just keys, they reach have a single account account, and the account has a "field" with the account balance.

Comment: I'll defer to @Dave any day when it comes to advice on building apps. Coding is just a hobby for me, so I'm only guessing when it comes to the big picture. Aside: Dave, just two more sleeps before the Nerf Rival Apollo XV-700 is released!

Comment: @CarySwoveland Tragically my advice is no better than anybody else's (or worse!) But on the Nerf gun I think there's no room for disagreement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize the hash entry to `0`. You can't index the number `0`.

If you want the value at the hash to be an object then you should have each hash entry be a new hash `{ dollar: 0 }`, one way being:

```
> totals = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = { dollar: 0 } }
> totals[:foo][:dollar] += 50
> totals
 => { :foo => { :dollar => 50 } }
> totals[:foo][:dollar] += 50
> totals[:bar][:dollar] += 10
> totals
 => { :foo => { :dollar => 100 }, :bar => { :dollar => 10 } }
```

Comment: Hi @Dave, thanks for the detailed explanation. Learned something new today. If you can, can you please breakdown the parameters of `Hash.new` please? Although the code works perfectly, I'd really like to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: @user3277633 The docs for `Hash.new` already break it down; nutshell is that you can pass nothing, pass a default value, or a block that creates the value for a given key when the key doesn't already exist in the hash.